# the advantages and disadvantages of multiple-line comments and one-line comments

Tags: comments

Many contemporary languages allow two kinds of comments: one in which delimiters are used on both ends (multiple-line comments), and one in which a delimiter marks only the beginning of the comments (one-line comments).  Discuss the advantages and disadvantages of each with respect to  criteria (readability, writability, reliability, cost).

Comment: While this is an interesting discussion, it is not well suited for a Q&A format like SO uses.

Answer (score 1):

There's no right answer here, they differ in a personal or style-wise way of coding.

With both you have a easy to write/read comment. The comment may be as long as you want, but generally short and precise comments are better, otherwise you would only be rewriting code as comment.

```
//assings 10 to x will make everything happier // the code won't change (further reading)
x = 10
if (x == 10) 
    happy++
```

How did this comment helped future users?

With multiple lines, though, you can write a little text, but reading it would be a little extra work if you still had to read (and understand) the code.
It won't change how programmers will read them, but they sure help when you have more than one line of comment (like reference URL's) and don't want to start every line with a comment markup.

I, personally, like multiline code for a simple reason: it agroups logical parts together

```
//*assings 10 to x will make everything happier //the code is on
x = 10
if (x == 10) 
    happy++
//*/
```

Now I can easily turn the code betwen those comments on and off that part of the code (for testing, for instance) only  by changing the first "/". It would be a advantage of multiline.

```
/*assings 10 to x will make everything happier // the code is off
x = 10
if (x == 10) 
    happy++
//*/
```